# What software does this wallet belong to?

Tags: wallets

I have a wallet from an older Ethereum client that has these contents:

`{"version":3,"id":"28fa9e4a-04ef-42ae-96de-661915a7c13d", "address":"0130c91e9d94c3e50b99f7ccf6d13babf5398e86", "Crypto":{"ciphertext":"redacted", "cipherparams":{"iv":"redacted"}, "cipher":"aes-128-ctr","kdf":"scrypt","kdfparams": {"dklen":32,"salt":"redacted","n":1024,"r":8,"p":1}, "mac":"redacted"}}`

What kind of wallet does this belong to? I have to guess and figure out the password.

Comment: It does look like a json v3 wallet. Metamask, MyEtherWallet, or MyCrypto should open that type of wallets.

Answer (score 0):

It is generic Ethereum wallet format. You should be able to open with most of wallet softwares like MyEthereumWallet and MyCrypto. Also software libraries like web3.js and web3.py support this format.